# Number from sample to be drawn from a Poisson distribution with upper/lower bounds

Tags: r, poisson

Working in `R`, I need to create a vector of length `n` with the values randomly drawn from a Poisson distribution with lambda=1, but with a lower bound of 2 and upper bound of 6 (i.e. all numbers will be either 2,3,4,5, or 6).

I am unsure how to do this. I tried creating a `for` loop that would replace any values outside that range with values inside the range:

```r
seed(123)
n<-25 #example length
example<-rpois(n,1)
test<-example #redundant - only duplicating to compare with original *example* values
 for (i in 1:length(n)){
   if (test[i]<2||test[i]>6){
     test[i]<-rpois(1,1)
   }
 }
```

But this didn't seem to work (still getting 0's and 1, etc, in `test`). Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You want to replace those values which is outside the range with what ? `which(example < 2 | example > 6)` gives all the indices to replace.

Comment: The Poisson distribution has infinite support over all natural numbers. So from a statistics point of view your question is not really clear. By imposing bounds on `X ~ Pois(lambda)` the resulting variable `X` will *not* be Poisson-distributed.

Comment: Thank you - to clarify, 1) I want to replace the positions outside of the range with randomly drawn values inside the range (2-6). 2) I do not need x to be Poisson distributed. In this specific case, I just need it to skew heavily towards 2, and have a non-zero probability for all values 2-6.

Comment: @jpsmith; how about weighting by the poisson prob dist. restricted to your defined support i.e. `p = dpois(2:6, 1); sample(2:6, n, replace=TRUE, prob = p/sum(p))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to generate `n` numbers with Poisson distribution and replace all the numbers which are outside range to random number inside the range.

```
n<-25 #example length
example<-rpois(n,1)
inds <- example < 2 | example > 6
example[inds] <- sample(2:6, sum(inds), replace = TRUE)
```